# Redirecting and exception my IP with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, web

I can't add the IP address of my computer to the exceptions, what could be the matter?

```
if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
    rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/some-page;
}
```

Comment: _Is_ the IP address that is making the request actually `127.0.0.1`? Not using IPv6 perhaps?

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the whole config https://pastebin.com/zaHB0RE5

Comment: now https://pastebin.com/LDt4xQH0